# How to search a JavaScript object key value using a variable?

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objects

For example, I have the object names:

`let names = {
    name: 'Jhon',
    lastName: 'Doe'
}`

Now, what I want to do is to search a key of the names object using a variable. 
For example I have the variable:

`let variable = 'lastName';`

What I want to do is to search the object key value like this:

`console.log(names.variable)`

And it should print Doe.
How can I do that?

Comment: like you would with an array: `console.log(names[variable]);`

Comment: @NinaScholtz You're probably looking for this duplicate instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable

Comment: @ControlAltDel it worked! Can you please comment it as an answer so I can mark it as the solution?